# C++ early dynamic initialization

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, static-initialization

In the current C++ standard, the paragraph [[basic.start.static] p.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static#3) says (emphasis mine):

> An implementation is permitted to perform the initialization of a
> variable with static or thread storage duration as a static
> initialization even if such initialization is not required to be done
> statically, provided that
>
> - **the dynamic version of the
>   initialization does not change the value of any other object of static
>   or thread storage duration prior to its initialization, and**
> - the
>   static version of the initialization produces the same value in the
>   initialized variable as would be produced by the dynamic
>   initialization if all variables not required to be initialized
>   statically were initialized dynamically. [...]

Why is the first condition so specific? Why would it be fine if the dynamic version of the initialization changed the value of other object of static or thread storage duration **after** its initialization? Why would it be fine for the dynamic initialization to have other side-effects at all?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be messing with a object until after it is initialized.

Comment: You don't want static initialization to overwrite the effects of a dynamic initialization. So I think what's meant is "the dynamic version of the initialization, *applied at this time*, would not change ...".

Comment: @NathanOliver But this paragraph is not the place to say this. And by moving the dynamic initialization to the "static phase", I believe that side-effect would be ignored, therefore allowing the change from dynamic to static initialization would avoid messing with the object before its initialized.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Could you please give an example of how violating this rule would end up with a static initialization overwriting the effects of a dynamic initialization? Thank you.

Comment: `auto foo() -> int { other_tu::bah = 666; return 42; } int this_tu::global = foo();` If the dynamic initialization here is replaced with `int this_tu::global = 42;` and effectively `other_tu::bah = 666;`, and the static initialization of the other translation unit later puts 1234 in `bah` (maybe it's *declared* there as `bah = 1234;`), you have an ungood race. Maybe there are also other dynamic initializations that try to change the `bah` value.

Comment: But I do not know if saying that *this_tu::global = foo(); would modify the value other_tu::bah **before its initialization*** is right, as I do not know how you would order initializations that do not belong to the same translation unit. Also, why would modifying the value after its initialization be alright? Take this for example: "int a = 1; int b = ++a;". If `b` was statically initialized, what value would a be initialized to?